# Python + Pyglet Cocos2D: TypeError: 'class' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, cocos2d-python

I've been working on a tiled map renderer, and I've tried to make a seperate Class in  another file. I get this error message:

```
Type Error: 'renderer' object is not callable
```

Here's the render.py file:

```
import pyglet, json
from pyglet.window import key
from pyglet.gl import *
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
from cocos.layer import *
from cocos.batch import *
from cocos.sprite import Sprite

class renderer( Layer ):
    def __init__(self, mapname):
        super( renderer, self ).__init__()
        parser = SafeConfigParser()
        try:
            world = parser.read('maps/'+mapname+'.txt')
            print world
        except IOError:
            print("No world file!")
            return
        layer = json.loads(parser.get('layer1', 'map'))
        tiletype = parser.get('type', 'tile')
        print tiletype
        tilesize = 64

        for x in range(0, len(layer)):
            for y in range(0, len(layer[x])):
                self.spr = Sprite("image/tiles/"+tiletype+"/"+str(layer[x][y])+".png")
                self.spr.position = ((x+1)*tilesize, (y+1)*tilesize)
                self.add(self.spr)
```

And this is the piece of code I call it with:

```
from other.render import renderer
```

```
world = renderer('buildnew')
world()
```

File Structure:

```
game/main.py
game/other/render.py
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
world = renderer('buildnew')
world()
```

First you make an instance of the renderer class and store it to world.
But then you write `world()`, which is wrong cause this object is not callable.
If you want to make `world` a callable object, you should implement the [`__call__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method in the renderer class.

Comment: Adding __call__ and putting the argument 'buildnew' to world() did solve the problem indeed. Thanks!